# Haskell group definition with span function

Tags: function, haskell, definition

I need to define group function is Haskell, but i just can do it with takeWhile and dropWhile, but i cant do it with span.
And i need to do it with span!
Could you help me?
Here my code with tW and dW:

```
group' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' [] = []
group' (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : group' (dropWhile (== x) xs)
```

Comment: what do you mean by can't do? is it giving error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 group' (x:xs) = a:(group' b) where (a,b) = span (==x) (x:xs)
```

Span simply returns two lists, which are separated using the given function.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I needed this kind of answer!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the definition of `span` in [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span), we find this useful hint:

> span p xs is equivalent to (takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)

So, as you defined your function as

```
group' [] = []
group' (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (==  x) xs) : group' (dropWhile (== x) xs)
```

You can easily see that your `p` in this case is `(== x)`. So, replacing it in the span definition above

```
span p xs = (takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)
span (== x) xs = (takeWhile (== x) xs, dropWhile (== x) xs)
```

span returns a pair of lists, so you can access them with `fst` and `snd`.
So we have that

```
takeWhile (== x) xs = fst (span (== x) xs)
```

and

```
dropWhile (== x) xs = snd (span (== x) xs)
```

Using this, we can then replace them in your original function like so:

```
group' [] = []    
group' (x:xs) = (x : fst (span (== x) xs) ) : group' (snd (span (== x) xs) )
```

Of course it's not nice to call the same function with the same arguments twice (`span (== x) xs`), so let's call it just once with a `let` binding:

```
group' [] = []
group' (x:xs) = let s = span (== x) xs in (x : (fst s)) : group' (snd s)
```

I love how Haskell is just maths in the end, and you can replace some definition (like the one you used with takeWhile and dropWhile) with others (span) using just some algebraic equations!

Comment: Of course my final expression could be further simplified by avoid using `fst` and `snd` as @manoj-r did, but I was more interested in showing you the steps I followed in my mind to get there.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, it was very useful to show the full method how to do it!